# Do interfaces need to specify implementation dependencies?

Tags: php, oop, interface

Taking the simplified example of a Dice interface that would return a random number between 1 and 6 and a DiceRoller interface that rolls a dice a specific number of times... How can the DiceRollerInterface specify that a DiceInterface should be used to generate rolls? Or is this not the responsibility of the interfaces?

PHP Example Interfaces:

```
interface DiceInterface
{
    public function roll();
}

interface DiceRollerInterface
{
    public function roll($times);
}
```

PHP Example Implementation

```
class DiceRoller implements DiceRollerInterface
{
    private $dice;

    public function __construct(DiceInterface $dice)
    {
        $this->dice = $dice;
    }

    public function roll($times)
    {
        $rolled = array();

        for ($i = 0; $i < $times; $i++) {
            $rolled[] =  $this->dice->roll();
        }

        return $rolled;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An interface is the technical implementation of an abstraction that is, an interface defines a behaviour. A class implementing an interface provides the actual implementation of that (or those, can be more than one) behaviour.

The point of using interfaces is to expose only the functionality a client requires without exposing everything the class might have. It's not the concern of an interface to specify implementation details such as what other dependencies the implementor must use. We are using interfaces because we don't want to be coupled to a specific implementation and we want the code to use *any* implementation.

So think of an interface as a contract (yeah...) which specifies the *what* and it doesn't care about the *how*. The only one interested in the *how* is its implementor and it's free to implement it in any way.